# Error running Jest tests after upgrading to Angular 9: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngModule' of undefined

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular9

I upgraded from Angular 8.2 to Angular 9. My project is working as expected, as is the build however many of the tests are failing with this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngModule' of undefined

  at isModuleWithProviders (../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:530:37)
  at expandModuleWithProviders (../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:523:7)
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at Function.get (../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:127:29)
  at getNgModuleDef (../packages/core/src/render3/definition.ts:761:27)
  at isNgModule (../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:534:12)
  at ../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:464:10
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at transitiveScopesFor (../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:458:30)
  at setScopeOnDeclaredComponents (../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:388:28)
  at Object.flushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible [as ɵflushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible] (../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:59:11)
  at TestBedRender3.flushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible [as checkGlobalCompilationFinished] (../../packages/core/testing/src/r3_test_bed.ts:400:7)
  at TestBedRender3.Object.<anonymous>.TestBedRender3.resetTestingModule (../../packages/core/testing/src/r3_test_bed.ts:231:10)
  at Function.Object.<anonymous>.TestBedRender3.resetTestingModule (../../packages/core/testing/src/r3_test_bed.ts:180:26)
  at ../../packages/core/testing/src/before_each.ts:25:13
  at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:386:30)
  at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:117:43)
  at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:385:36)
  at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:143:47)
```

This is an example of a very simple test that fails:

```
import { ExampleModule } from './example.module';

describe('ExampleModule', () => {
   let exampleModule: ExampleModule;

  beforeEach(() => {
    exampleModule = new ExampleModule();
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    expect(exampleModule).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with barrel imports. To fix I had to remove all barrel imports and deep import all files.

example of old:

```
import {
  Example1,
  Example2
} from 'path/to/example-folder';
```

example of new:

```
import { Example1 } from 'path/to/example1-file';
import { Example2 } from 'path/to/example2-file';
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was about the exports of the component/module I need to import in other module. So the problem was not in the import, but in the exports. Instead of:

```
export { FirstComponent } from './first.component';
export { FirstModule } from './first.module';
```

I need to export it as:

```
export * from './first.component';
export * from './first.module';
```

No more `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngModule' of undefined` after this in Angular 13.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and it turned out that the root cause was in Circular dependencies, which is not very intuitive based on the stacktrace. Resolving circular imports solved the issue.

There is an original tread in the Angular's repo which contains more details
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/39573